# Python SQLite3- Query return an empty list even if the searched row is present

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I can't understand why this function print an empty list.
Main is passing start = 'London' and end = 'Rome'

```
def get_trip_with(self, Start, End):
     list = []
     with sqlite3.connect(db_file) as conn:
          cursor = conn.cursor()
          cursor.execute(str("SELECT * FROM trip WHERE From_where IN (?,?) AND To_where IN (?,?)"),\
                    (Start, End, Start, End,))
          print(f'{(cursor.fetchall())}')
```

Because if i separate the query into 2 different ones like:

```
def get_trip_with(self, Start, End):
     list = []
     with sqlite3.connect(db_file) as conn:
          cursor = conn.cursor()
          cursor.execute(str("SELECT * FROM trip WHERE From_where IN (?,?)"),\
                    (Start, End,))
          print(f'{(cursor.fetchall())}')
          print(f'{(cursor.fetchall())}')
          cursor.execute(str("SELECT * FROM trip WHERE To_where IN (?,?)"),\
                    (Start, End,))
          print(f'{(cursor.fetchall())}')
```

I end up with a bunch of trip including one (found by both queries) from London to Rome. The question is why the first query (script 1) can't find this trip(from London to Rome) but the queries in the second script can?
Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: Mea culpa, I made a mistake while copying, the problem is still the same and i have no idea why that happens

Comment: You forgot to mention what you expect from your query. Edit your question and explain the requirement.

Comment: Aside - in Python, values inside any parentheses does not need the `\` line break operator.

Comment: Do note your first query has an `AND` operator between conditions unlike the latter two queries.

Comment: Your query works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b064a7220bd4a8daaf57b3cf45976fb7 so I guess maybe this is not your actual code.

Comment: @forpas i know that, in fact if i try the query on SqliteMan it does show me the trip but on python it just print: []

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible with the code that you posted.